# Logging incoming requests at a Pod in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

In my cluster, I am interested in service time at the Pod level (time difference between request arrival and departure), thus it would be integral to log incoming and outgoing requests (IP address or request ID, event timestamp).

I am aware of the capability to define custom logs using containers (from [Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/)), however I'm looking for a more dynamic solution with a smaller over head (hopefully exposed over the REST API).

Comment: Have you considered bundling a reverse proxy such as envoy, haproxy, linkerd, nginx, etc, as a side-car container and pointing the Service at that? They are built for what you are describing, and would free your application from the need to do that by itself

Comment: That is an option, however I feel this would be an unnecessary overhead that would consume resources on my cluster. A more appropriate solution might be to directly log such data at the Service level; since it's the endpoint.